# Llamar el metodo de una clase que recibe parametros de otra clase y poder definirlo para usar su resultado en otra función fuera de la clase

Tags: python-3.x, poo, diseño-de-clases

les cuento que soy nuevo en Python y me encuentro bloqueado en una parte del código que estoy usando para hacer trading de manera autónoma.

Necesito utilizar el resultado del metodo `def historicalDataEnd(self, reqId, start, end):`, el inconveniente que tengo es que los parámetros que usa el método son dados por el servidor del broker.

Usualmente el código trabaja con una función que solicita el dato que requiero que en este caso seria `reqHistoricalData(2, contract, currentTime, '2 D', '5 mins', 'TRADES', 0, 2, False, [])`, este mensaje se envía a la estación de trading el cual autentica el cliente, y después envía el mensaje solicitando el dato que requiero a los servidores del broker, cuando se tiene la respuesta del mensaje, este se envía nuevamente a la estación de trading (software en mi pc) y finalmente obtengo la respuesta la cual es procesada por el método de la función que es un CallBack  `def historicalDataEnd(self, reqId, start, end):`

El dilema que presento es que quiero asignarle un nombre al resultado de este método para usarlo en un nueva función y poder compararlo con el resultado de otros métodos en una nueva función, pero al momento de definirlo y llamarlo, me indica que no le estoy dando ningún parámetro, el problema es que los parámetros se envían de vuelta desde el servidor del broker a la estación de trading y de ahí editor de texto el cual es luego impreso el resultado en la consola.

Conclusión como trabaja: cliente (yo) > estación de trading >servidor del broker > estación de trading > cliente (yo).

Agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda a este novato, y por otro lado me excuso si no utilice los nombres adecuados para exponer mi ejemplo. 
Aquí dejo el código usado:

```
''' Demonstrates how to compute the moving average '''

from datetime import datetime
from threading import Thread
import time
import collections

from ibapi.client import EClient, Contract
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.utils import iswrapper


class MovingAverage(EWrapper, EClient):
    ''' Serves as the client and the wrapper '''

    def __init__(self, addr, port, client_id):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)

        # Initialize members
        self.stock_vals = collections.deque(maxlen=13) #This number define SMA # 13
        self.avg_vals = []

        self.stock_vals_2 = collections.deque(maxlen=20) #This number define SMA # 20
        self.avg_vals_2 = []

        # Connect to TWS
        self.connect(addr, port, client_id)

        # Launch the client thread
        thread = Thread(target=self.run)
        thread.start()

    @iswrapper
    def historicalData(self, reqId, bar): <--- Parametros enviamos por el broker
        # Append the closing price to the deque
        self.stock_vals.append(bar.close)
        self.stock_vals_2.append(bar.close)


        # Compute the average if 13 values are available
        if len(self.stock_vals) == 13:
            avg = sum(self.stock_vals) / len(self.stock_vals)
            self.avg_vals.append(avg)
            self.avg = avg


        # Compute the average if 20 values are available
        if len(self.stock_vals_2) == 20:
            avg_2 = sum(self.stock_vals_2) / len(self.stock_vals_2)
            self.avg_vals_2.append(avg_2)
            self.avg_20 = avg_2  ------> # Necesito utilizar este resultado en una nueva función



    @iswrapper
    def historicalDataEnd(self, reqId, start, end):
            print('SMA 20: {}'.format(self.avg_vals_2[-1]))
            print('SMA 13: {}'.format(self.avg_vals[-1]))


    def error(self, reqId, code, msg):
        print('Error {}: {}'.format(code, msg))



def main():
    # Create the client and connect to TWS
    client = MovingAverage('127.0.0.1', 7497, 1)

    # Define a contract for IBM stock
    contract = Contract()
    contract.symbol = "MNQ"
    contract.secType = "FUT"
    contract.exchange = "GLOBEX"
    contract.currency = "USD"
    contract.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth = 202006

    # Solicita el dato historico a HistoricalData 
    currentTime = datetime.today().strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S")
    client.reqHistoricalData(1, contract, currentTime, '2 D', '5 mins', 'TRADES', 0, 2, False, [])



    # Sleep while the request is processed
    time.sleep(5)

    # Disconnect from TWS
    client.disconnect()

if __name__ : '__main__':
     main()
```

Comment: No se si estaré muy perdido, pero `avg_20` es un atributo de instancia, puedes acceder a él siempre que tengas una referencia al objeto (`cliente` en `main`) con `datos = cliente.avg_20`. No obstante, solo puedes haber ésto después de que el método `historicalData` se llame y aún así puede que no exista el atributo ya que se define en un condicional. La clase no sigue la buena práctica de inicializar todo atributo en el `__init__`... Otra opción es usar `datos = getattr(datos, "avg_20", None)`.

Comment: @FJSevilla Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. La estructura del código lo estoy utilizando de uno ya prediseñado. Intentare probar lo que me dices, por otra parte, como debería ser la buena practicado con el constructor __init__?  Seguiré intentado, nuevamente muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Lo recomendable es declarar e inicializar todos los atributos, especialmente si son "públicos" en el incializador. De ésta forma existen siempre una vez instanciada la clase. Si no tiene un valor porque dependan de un método que se ejecutará después lo suyo es hacer algo como `self.avg_20 = None` o que se obtenga el valor real directamente desde el inicializador al instanciar o usar una property que lo llame directamente, de forma que cada vez que hagamos datos = self,avg_20 se haga una nuva petición y se actualice el valor del atributo, etc.

Comment: La idea es que el atributo exista siempre. y que no tengamos una excepción por intentar referenciarlo antes de que el método que lo crea se ejecutara o la condición se cumpliera, lo normal es recibir un valor de None en éstos casos no una excepción... Si no, al menos se debería marcar como privado con un _ delante del nombre, para indicar que no se debe acceder a él directamente.

Comment: @FJSevilla Perfecto, gracias por tu respuesta. Intentare hacer lo que me dices, entendiste mi punto como lo quería exponer.

Comment: @FJSevilla Hola, al intentar acceder al atributo me arroja el siguiente error: AttributeError: type object 'MovingAverage' has no attribute 'avg_20. Tanto usando `datos = cliente.avg_20`, cómo usando `datos = getattr(datos,"avg_20",None)`, de hecho este ultimo me arroja como resultado `None`. 
Intentare darle el valor real directamente desde el inicializador. 
Vaya que me ha dado lucha, muchas gracias nuevamente.

Comment: Es precisamente a lo que me refería con todo lo anterior, haces eso antes de que historicalData sea llamada o aún así, si no se cae en  if len(self.stock_vals_2) == 20:, el atributo no existirá.

Comment: @FJSevilla La verdad, ya no sé qué hacer, me quede bloqueado ahí. No sé como hacer lo que tú me sugieres. De todas formas, te agradezco por tu colaboración. Saludos.